# How to hide and show by using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have loaded **.obj** file using **three.js**. I want to **show** and **hide** .obj file on **button**. After page loading click on button object is show but How to hide that object on same button. There is no 

or

. So it is very hard to Hide&Show. Pls Check below Link.

[Run Code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandipnd31/08dkxjwg/)

```
<button type="button" style="z-index: 12345;position: absolute;margin-left: 50%;" id="hideShow">Hide / Show!</button>



<script>

var objHidden = false;

document.getElementById("hideShow").addEventListener("click", function(){


 var loader1 = new THREE.OBJLoader();
// load a resource
loader1.load(
    // resource URL
    'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pn3yw6w5962o5r8/BIGIPIGI.obj',
    // called when resource is loaded
    function ( object ) {
        scene.add(object);
        object.scale.set(2.15,2.15,2.15);
        object.position.set(-4.5, 5.3, 5.6);

         object.traverse( function ( child ) {
           if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                //child.material.ambient.setHex(0xFF0000);
                child.material.color.setHex(0xaa0000);
               }
           } );
    },      
);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping a variable of whether its hidden or not.

```
var objHidden = false;

document.getElementById("hideShow").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(objHidden) {
        objHidden = false;
        // code to show object
    } else {
        objHidden = true;
        // code to hide object
    }
});
```

Comment: use `object.visible = false;` to hide and `object.visible = true;` to show. take a look at the docs for Object3D https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D

Comment: How, I dont know sir

Comment: Hello Sir, pls check this question   https://discourse.threejs.org/t/hot-to-get-pop-up-modal-after-clicking-on-the-object/1255

Comment: Check out this question for more info on marking answers correct. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: try to help me for this question https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-move-two-object-at-time/1403/13